# DualBoot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD + HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, ssd

I have a notebook with 32GB SSD with Windows 8.1 installed and am thinking of installing Ubuntu 14.04 on dualboot, I have done a search online, but I'm still in doubt about which is the best way to install and configure the system so that both work without problems. I saw that some people had problems and as my knowledge is more User level I would like some advice and tips to prevent it.

Incidentally, it is possible to maintain the SSD just for Windows and create a partition on the HD to Ubuntu?

I thank the attention.

PS: My notebook is in this link below:

http://www.lojahp.com.br/Voce/Ultrabook/Ultrabook-HP-Pavilion-14-B080BR-com-Intel-Core-i5-3317U-Windows-8-32GB-SSD-4GB-500GB-Leitor-de-Cartoes-HDMI-Wireless-Bluetooth-LED-14-1834802.html?recsource=busca-int&rectype=busca-838

Comment: Are you sure Windows is on 32GB SSD and it is not just the Intel SRT cache and Windows is really on the hard drive also? Post this. sudo parted -l If an Ultrabook you probably have the Intel SRT which uses RAID, fastboot, secure boot, UEFI and dual video issues to work around. All very doable, but makes it a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I have not much knowledge in this area. How do I check if Windows is installed on the SSD? To help answer that question any more information is needed? If yes, how can I get it?

Comment: Check this article http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html